# How do I update gdk_rgb_cmap_new from gtk2 to gtk3?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

I'm trying to update some software from GTK2 to GTK3; I've had some success, but I'm running into problems, particularly related to colormaps.

Everything I have read says that a **GDKColormap** needs to be replaced by a **GDKVisual**, and that graphics should be rendered using **Cairo**.  I understand - more or less - how **GDKVisual** works, but I have one particular problem: **gdk_rgb_cmap_new(...)**.  It seems as though this function has no equivalent in **GDKVisual**, and that it isn't possible to pass in "private" (i.e. our own design) colormaps into GTK3.  Is this the case now?  If it is, how are we supposed to use our own colormaps in GTK3-based software?  Do we have to manually edit the image to be displayed via **Cairo** (which also appears to have no colormap-based functions) ourselves instead?

This may be too specific a question for here, but I can't find an obvious GTK+ forum to ask it on, so if anyone has any pointers as to where might be better to ask it, then please say so.

Update:

In GTK2, we used the function **gdk_draw_indexed_image(...)**, which had an argument that took a **GDKColormap**, which could be created using **gdk_rgb_cmap_new(...)**.  I am now trying to use Cairo to do something similar via the cairo function **cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(...)**, but as colormaps no longer exist, I can't see how to use (for example) **cairo_set_source_rgba(...)** to get the same effect as the colormap argument has in **gdk_draw_indexed_image(...)**, unless we manually edit the image data ourselves before passing it in to the function.

I'm not sure how the expose event is relevant: I have edited the GTK2 code

```
gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (canvas), "expose_event", (GtkSignalFunc) repaint_proc, (gpointer) tv_screen);
```

to the GTK3 code

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (canvas), "draw", G_CALLBACK (repaint_proc), (gpointer) tv_screen);
```

but I'm not sure how that's relevant to the colormap issue.

Comment: I believe this is on-topic here. You may want to post a code example so people understand what you're doing. I'm afraid I personally can't help you, but welcome!

Comment: Are you trying to do a line-by-line conversion of low-level GDK code? If so, you're probably taking the wrong approach. Show your `expose` event handler and we can see what you need to do to make a proper `draw` handler.

Comment: New information added to the question.